# Why is there no Picture in my Panel/Window?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

whats wrong with my code? I just want to have a Picture in my Window...

```
//class ImagePanel:

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7664761101121497912L;

    public Image i;

    public ImagePanel(Image i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);        
        g.drawImage(this.i, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

//class Main

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImagePanel panel = null;

        try {
            panel = new ImagePanel(ImageIO.read(new File("D:/test.JPG")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

There is just a Window without a picture :(
Whats the problem? And is there an easy way to set size of the window == picture size?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, when calling ``g.drawImage``, you want to pass ``this`` as the 4th arg. That way, if ``i`` is not completely loaded (e.g., fetched over the network), repaint will be called when the loading is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paintComponent`**s**`(Graphics g)`.

Comment: +1 Good eye! `@Override` won't catch this, because it a legitimate `Container` method.

Comment: Thanks, I used to made this mistake serveral times.

Comment: oh lol. Yeah not it works. Thank you Genzer, you got nice eyes :)

Comment: @mirko, and if you would use a JLabel instead of reinventing the wheel you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: sometimes... if you want to learn stuff, you have to try to "reinverting the wheel". And sometimes if you just need an application what works (without brain.exe) you can use JLabel :) This time I want to learn...

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use a JLabel. Don't reinvent wheel. There is no need for you to do custom painting.

But if you do custom painting then you need to override the getPreferredSize() method to be the size of the image so the layout manager can do their job.

Comment: I'm not good at Swing. But supposed I want my `JPanel` to have a background image, then I will use a `JLabel` to paint this background, and other components will be added into this `JLabel`? It sounds awkward to me.

Comment: A JLabel is a Container, just like a JPanel. You can set the layout and add components to it.

Answer (score 3):

please read this tutorials about [Icon in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) and your Image would by placed to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) but with same way/funcioanlities as to the [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

Comment: Hi. Thx this is a nice one too. But I would like to use this way with my extraclass ImagePanel. I just dont understand whats the problem with the code...

Answer (score 0):

I not at all familiar with Java panes, but don't you need to set the size of ImagePanel before you add it to the content pane.

Comment: Layout managers are more likely to honor the preferred size than the size.